# xmlhttp.responseText and xmlhttp.readyState works fine with localhost but if i use IP address it is not returning values same as localhost

Tags: html

`xmlhttp.responseText` and `xmlhttp.readyState` works fine with localhost but if i use IP address it is not returning values same as localhost.

```
    function getFilenames()
    {               
        xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlhttp==null)
        {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
        }
        var url="GetFileNames.php";
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }

    function stateChanged()
    {   
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        {
            StringFileName = xmlhttp.responseText; 
        }
        else
        {
            StringFileName = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check properly the path . We faced this situation earlier.

e.g.

```
//This path is for local
var url="http://" + location.host +"/path/some.aspx";


//This path is for DEV Server
var url="http://" + location.host +"/path.net/path/some.aspx";
```

Hope this helps